# WebStorm IDE responds with ", or ) expected" in the parameters section when analyzing a function?

Tags: javascript, parameters, webstorm, default-value

Why does the javascript IDE respond with ", or ) expected" in the parameters section when analyzing the following function?

```
function xPositionFunc(statement=true) {
if(statement) {
    xPosition = (Math.floor((allPctToEachLongLine[0] * WIDTH) + Math.floor((num * 24)) * (allPctToEachLongLine[1]) * WIDTH));
}
else{
    xPosition = (Math.floor((allPctToEachLongLine[0] * WIDTH) + Math.floor((num * 24)) * (allPctToEachLongLine[1]) * WIDTH)) - map_crosshair_dimensions/2 + 3;
}
return xPosition;
```

}

I am using the IDE WebStorm by JetBrains. It tells me `, or ) expected` in the parameters of the function.

Comment: Which version of JavaScript? Default values are new in ES2015 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: The ES2015 version.

Comment: And is that what you've chosen in WebStorm? See e.g. https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/05/ecmascript-6-in-webstorm-transpiling/

Comment: Aha! That seems to be the problem. I did not set javascript to version ECMAScript 6.Thank you, jonrsharpe.